# Symfony SPAM log with 404

Tags: php, symfony, monolog

I have encounter the following issue: my symfony application keeps spamming the log with

```
request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET
```

When no route is found. I have configured my monolog (config_prod.yml) handlers as follows:

```
monolog:
  handlers:
    main:
        type:         fingers_crossed
        action_level: error
        handler:      nested
        excluded_404s:
            - .*
    nested:
        type:  stream
        path:  "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
        level: debug
    console:
        type:  console
```

Yet, I still get the 404 logged as error.

Can anyone help?

Comment: remove the `excluded_404s` line as it's enabled by default when running your app in *prod* mode

Comment: @LBA Did not help. Still got the 404 logged in my var/logs/prod.log

Comment: excluded_404s with `- ^/` works fine at my app. Did you clear the cache (application and possible opcache)?